# NetBeans Not Working, New Projects On Linux

Tags: java, netbeans

I installed Netbeans today, and downloaded java JDK yesterday.

When i try to create a new project it douse nothing. I checked if i have java JDK in the terminal by typing

```
#Terminal
java -version.

#Output
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-02-17
openJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Debian-1)
openJDK 64-bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Debian-1, mixed mode)
```

I have:

```
#NetBans File
netbeans-8.2-linux.sh

#Java JDK
jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

Comment: [1] What version of NetBeans did you install? [2] What versions of Java do you have defined as Java Plaforms in NetBeans? (**Tools > Java Platforms**)?

Comment: I added the file name...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetBeans 8.2 Won't Run/Open on Mac all of sudden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53108770/2985643). The problem is that you are trying to use NetBeans 8.2 with JDK > 8, which is unsupported. The selected answer for the question I linked to details what you need to do.

Comment: I use linux....

Comment: The [answer I linked to tells you what you need to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113462/2985643). What does using Linux have to do with fixing the configuration of NetBeans?

Comment: Different setup for java jdk on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans 8.2 isn't compatible with Java 10. Download the latest version. The support to Java 9 and 10 was added in Netbeans 9. You can see more here:

http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/