# The Services under window menue does not work

Tags: netbeans

My NetBeans enviroment information is:
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2 Java: 11.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.1+13-LTS Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 11.0.1+13-LTS System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb) User directory: C:\Users\eebrwal\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2

Cache directory: C:\Users\eebrwal\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2
But when I press Services under Windows menu it does not do anything!

Please help if you can.

Waleed

Comment: Is that the only problem you have when opening a panel in NetBeans? For example, does it work if you do **Window > Navigator** or **Window > Files** or **Windows > Tasks**?

Comment: Window > Files does not work.
New Project does not work.
New File does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using JDK 11 on NetBeans 8.2. That combination just won't work.

You have four options:

- Configure Netbeans 8.2 to use JDK 8 instead, since that is the most recent JDK that NetBeans 8.2 supports. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113462/2985643) for details on how to do that.
- [Download and install NetBeans 9.0](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html), which will allow you to use JDK 9 and/or JDK 10 as well.
- Wait for NetBeans 10 which will allow you to use JDK 11. It should be released in the next week or two.
- [Download and install a beta version of NetBeans 10](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/10vc3) and use JDK 11 at your own risk.